# Zooming from center of the screen in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a div that I can pan and zoom in & out with my mouse. Panning works just fine but when I zoom the zoom seems to originate from the top-left corner of the screen and not the middle of it - When the div is in that corner it zooms and stays in its place but when it is further down the screen it drifts toward the bottom-right corner as I zoom.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2al4e

Code:

Zooming:

```
@HostListener('window:wheel', ['$event'])
onScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
  if (this.isDragging) return;

  const delta = event.deltaY;
  const sign = delta / Math.abs(delta);
  if (Math.abs(delta) > this.SCROLL_THRESH) {
    const scaleChange = Math.pow(
      this.SCALE_STEP,
      -sign * 0.05 * Math.abs(delta)
    );
    let oldScale = this.scale;
    this.scale *= scaleChange;
    this.scale = this.clamp(this.scale, this.MIN_SCALE, this.MAX_SCALE);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="ex"
[ngStyle]="{
  transform:
    'scale(' +
    scale +
    ') translate(' +
    translateX +
    'px, ' +
    translateY +
    'px)'
}"
>
  x: {{translateX}}<br/>y: {{translateY}}<br/> scale: {{scale}}
</div>
```

How can I make is so the the zoom originates in the middle of the screen?